# Ansible task create directory and after it check if exist fail

Tags: python, ansible

I have the following task that check if the directory exist and if it doesn't then I create it, then a bit later I check if it was created to do more stuff, but it fail. What am I missing?

```
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  vars:
     shared_path: /usr/local/apps/shared
     releases_path: /usr/local/apps/releases

  tasks:
   - name: shared_path exists
     stat: path={{shared_path}}
     register: sp

   - name: releases_path exists
     stat: path={{releases_path}}
     register: rp

   - include: tasks/setup.application.yml
     when: sp.stat.isdir is not defined and rp.stat.isdir is not defined

   - include: tasks/deploy.application.releases.yml
     when: sp.stat.isdir is defined and rp.stat.isdir is defined
```

I am running:

```
ansible 2.7.10
  config file = /home/MYUSER/Desktop/Ansible/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/MYUSER/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not re-setting `sp` and `rp`.  You need to re-run the `stat` module after the `setup.application.yml` task:

```
  tasks:
   - name: shared_path exists
     stat: path={{shared_path}}
     register: sp

   - name: releases_path exists
     stat: path={{releases_path}}
     register: rp

   - include: tasks/setup.application.yml
     when: sp.stat.isdir is not defined and rp.stat.isdir is not defined

   - name: shared_path exists
     stat: path={{shared_path}}
     register: sp

   - name: releases_path exists
     stat: path={{releases_path}}
     register: rp

   - include: tasks/deploy.application.releases.yml
     when: sp.stat.isdir is defined and rp.stat.isdir is defined
```

Comment: I did that and it failed too. Seems like the task include on `setup.application.yml` has not completed therefore even if I remove the "when" it fail too. How could I wait until the previous task has completed?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Is the second `inculde` task being skipped, or is it failing?

Comment: It is been skipped.

Comment: Throw in a `debug` task just before the `deploy.application.releases.yml`.  Let's see what's in there.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it pointed me on the right direction. I had an issue on the first set of task that were included. Thank you.